# Using CsvMapper in Kotlin to parse huge CSV file

Tags: kotlin, exception, csvmapper

I have a CSV file generated as a report by the server. The CSV file has more than 100k lines of text. I'm reading the file in Kotlin using CsvMapper, but I'm ending up with IOException.

Here's the code that I'm implemented:

```
//Declare the mapper object
private var csvMapper = CsvMapper().registerModule(KotlinModule())
        
//Generate Iterator
inline fun <reified T> getIterator(fileName: String): MappingIterator<T>? {
    csvMapper.disable(JsonParser.Feature.AUTO_CLOSE_SOURCE)
    FileReader(fileName).use { reader ->
        return csvMapper
                       .readerFor(T::class.java)
                       .without(StreamReadFeature.AUTO_CLOSE_SOURCE)
                       .with(CsvSchema.emptySchema().withHeader())
                       .readValues<T>(reader)
    }
}
    
//Read the file using iterator
fun read(csvFile: String) {
    val iterator = getIterator<BbMembershipData>(csvFile)
    if (iterator != null) {
          while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                try {
                     val lineElement = iterator.next()
                     println(lineElement)
                } catch (e: RuntimeJsonMappingException) {
                    println("Iterator Exception: " + e.localizedMessage)
                }
          }
     }
}
```

After printing 10 lines of code, its throwing below exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Stream closed
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.MappingIterator._handleIOException(MappingIterator.java:420)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.MappingIterator.next(MappingIterator.java:203)
    at Main$FileProcessor.read(Main.kt:39)
    at Main.main(Main.kt:54)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Stream closed
```

How can I prevent the "Stream Closed" exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way `CsvMapper` works is that it reads *lazily*, rather than reading the whole file the moment you call `readValues`.

When the end of the `use` block is reached, basically nothing has actually been read yet! You only start reading the file when you start using the iterator, but by then, the file is already closed!

Therefore, `read` needs to open and close the file, not `getIterator`:

```
//Generate Iterator
inline fun <reified T> getIterator(reader: Reader): MappingIterator<T>? {
    csvMapper.disable(JsonParser.Feature.AUTO_CLOSE_SOURCE)
    return csvMapper
                   .readerFor(T::class.java)
                   .without(StreamReadFeature.AUTO_CLOSE_SOURCE)
                   .with(CsvSchema.emptySchema().withHeader())
                   .readValues<T>(reader)
    
//Read the file using iterator
fun read(csvFile: String) {
    FileReader(csvFile).use { reader ->
        val iterator = getIterator<BbMembershipData>(reader)
        if (iterator != null) {
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                try {
                    val lineElement = iterator.next()
                    println(lineElement)
                } catch (e: RuntimeJsonMappingException) {
                    println("Iterator Exception: " + e.localizedMessage)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Notice how the end of the `use` block changed, to where you finish reading the whole file.